# th:action with function from javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have this call:

```
<button th:action="@{/engines/selectedEnginesForParse}"+"{addids()}">1</button>
```

I have this javascript function.

```
function addIds() {
        return 1;

    }
```

How can I make this, i.e, call javascript function on th:action path?